# Input Text select() through onkeydown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I copied an element from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_text_select); 
`document.getElementById("myTdext").select();`

and tried enabling Input Text select() through `onkeydown`, but it doesn't seem to work like the example (the external link above.)

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="idname" type="text" onkeydown="myFunction(event)">

<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var input = document.getElementById("idname").focus();
  }
function myFunction(event) {
  var x = event.which || event.keyCode;
  if (x == 40) { //ArrowDown
  document.getElementById("idname").select(); // <- this is the copied element
}
}
</script>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the keyup property instead of keydown, because when you use keydown it will undo the focus on keyup again.

You also you need to place myFunction outside of the window.onload(), otherwise you can't call it:

```js
function myFunction(event) {
    var x = event.which || event.keyCode;
    if (x == 40) { //ArrowDown
        document.getElementById("idname").select();
    }
 }

 window.onload = function() {
     var input = document.getElementById("idname").focus();
 }
```

```html
<input id="idname" type="text" onkeyup="myFunction(event)">
```